# Git merge main not making any changes

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch

I have my `main` branch and another branch `feature`. I checked out `feature` committed my changes, and did `git merge main`. It said `Already up to date`, but none of the changes from `main` appear in `feature`. Am I doing the merge wrong?

Comment: So if I'm on `feature` and do `git merge main` and it says `Already up to date`, do you mean that `Already up to date` isn't saying anything about the result of the merge, but rather is saying something about the state of the branch I'm on (`feature`)?

Comment: Comment expanded to answer.

Answer (score 0):

"Already up to date" isn't a description of the state *after* the command did something, it's a message printed *instead of* doing something: "Nothing needs to be done, because the branch is already up to date".

More specifically, it is saying that all the commits reachable from the local branch pointer called "main" are also reachable from the currently checked out commit. Or, roughly speaking, "everything on main is already on the current branch".

If you think there *should have been* something to merge, one possibility is that you are looking at a branch called "main" on some other copy of the repository - on Github, for instance. To reference that branch, you first "fetch" it and then reference the "remote-tracking branch" in the form "name-of-remote/name-of-branch". The default "remote" (alias for another repository) is called "origin", so the common sequence of commands is:

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/main
```

The combination of fetch + merge can be abbreviated with the "pull" command, like so:

```
git pull origin main
```

This too will say "Already up to date" if it can't see anything that needs merging.

Answer (score -1):

But why you want to merge `main` into `feature` after you have make changes in `feature`? That doesn‘t make any sense. I think, `feature` was created from `main`, and if you don‘t make any changes in `main`, there are nothing to `git merge` from `main` in `feature`.

Do you want to *merge* the changes from `feature` in `main`? Because the opposite way makes no sense in a declared situatio... Then `git checkout main` and `git merge feature`. Or create a Pull Request from `feature` to `main` and approve the changes. After this, the changes will also merged into `main`.